# ruby on rails view template

Tags: css

In my Rails application's final view I need to display hundreds of records. When I see my output I see that its gradually sliding towards the center and slowly towards the right fully. I tried left align but its not working.

```
<%= will_paginate @tweets %>
<% @tweets.each do |tweets| %>
<ul>
  <li><%= tweets.id %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.tweet_created_at %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.tweet_text %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_id %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_name %></li>      
  <li><%= tweets.user_loc %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_img %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.longitude %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.latitude %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.place %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.country %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

When I need to display a large number of records it's fully sliding to the right end of screen. How to solve this issue?

Comment: I don't know why you tag this Ruby and Ruby on Rails. You have to fix this using CSS. Maybe you can include a screenshot showing the problem, because from your description it's very unclear what you mean exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be either one from below `two options.`
`UL` tag is not being ended properly.

option 1  :

```
<%= will_paginate @tweets %>
<% @tweets.each do |tweets| %>
<ul>
  <li><%= tweets.id %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.tweet_created_at %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.tweet_text %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_id %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_name %></li>      
  <li><%= tweets.user_loc %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_img %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.longitude %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.latitude %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.place %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.country %></li>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

or Option 2

```
 <%= will_paginate @tweets %>
    <ul>
    <% @tweets.each do |tweets| %>
      <li><%= tweets.id %></li>
      <li><%= tweets.tweet_created_at %></li>
      <li><%= tweets.tweet_text %></li>
      <li><%= tweets.user_id %></li>
      <li><%= tweets.user_name %></li>      
      <li><%= tweets.user_loc %></li>
      <li><%= tweets.user_img %></li>
      <li><%= tweets.longitude %></li>
      <li><%= tweets.latitude %></li>
      <li><%= tweets.place %></li>
      <li><%= tweets.country %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
```

Comment: thanks a lot first option I got the output